# Need to tweak DAX to show correct total figure in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

My current Measure in Power BI is:

```
JobCount5 =
CALCULATE (
    COUNTX (
        ALLEXCEPT (
            Calls,
            Status[Status Type],
            Fault[Fault ID],
            Lifts[Lift Type],
            CustomerAndAgent[Customer Name],
            Sites[Site ID]
        ),
        CALCULATE (
            COUNT ( Calls[Job] ),
            FILTER (
                ALLSELECTED ( Sites ),
                'Sites'[Site ID] = MAX ( Sites[Site ID] )
            )
        )
    ),
    CROSSFILTER ( Calls[SiteIDLine], Lifts[SiteIDLine], ONEWAY )
)
```

This gives me:

[image]

The values in the rows are all fine and correct, but the total is way out. Its something to do with the MAX function I would guess, but I have been unable to figure it out and return correct values in the table. Would love it if someone can help me out with it?

Cheers for all help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the quickest solution would be to replace

```
'Sites'[Site ID] = MAX ( Sites[Site ID] )
```

with

```
'Sites'[Site ID] IN VALUES ( Sites[Site ID] )
```

This allows for any `Site ID` in the current filter context rather than just the maximal one.

---

I think your measure could be simplified quite a bit. Instead of nested iterators, you could try something structured more like this:

```
JobCount5 =
CALCULATE (
    COUNTROWS (
        ALLEXCEPT (
            Calls,
            Status[Status Type],
            Fault[Fault ID],
            Lifts[Lift Type],
            CustomerAndAgent[Customer Name],
            Sites[Site ID]
        )
    ),
    ALLSELECTED ( Sites ),
    'Sites'[Site ID] IN VALUES ( Sites[Site ID] ),
    CROSSFILTER ( Calls[SiteIDLine], Lifts[SiteIDLine], ONEWAY )
)
```

I can't guarantee that this will work since I haven't tested it, but hopefully, it will point you in the right direction.

Comment: Hi Alexis, I have tried this but I now get a value of 12704 for EVERY row in the whole table, even those that should have been filtered out, and the total at the bottom of the table is also 12704. The total I am expecting is 122 :). This is when using the more complete solution you suggested. Any further guidance?

Comment: Editing just the one part of my original DAX statement per your first suggestion works perfectly though, so I may just use that if I cannot work out how to change your second suggestion to make it work